# The notation of graph Fourier transform

Tags: graph-theory, fourier-transform, spectral-graph-theory

In spectral graph theory, given $N \times N$ graph Laplacian matrix $L$ and the graph signal $f \in \mathbb R^N$ , the graph Fourier transform is defined as:

$\hat{f}(l)=\langle u_l , f\rangle$ (inner product)

where $L=U \Lambda U^{-1}$, $u_l$ is a column of $U$ ($l=0,...,N-1$).

But in some places, it is written as:

$\hat{f}(\lambda_l)=\langle u_l , f\rangle$.

I'm confused about this second notation. I think this $\hat{f}(\lambda_l)$ notation is ill-defined.

---

Consider a graph with the Laplacian $L$ in the image below. The corresponding eigen decomposition is shown also.

[image]

Then let's define a graph signal $f=[1,2,3,4]^T$.

The graph Fourier transform result is shown:

[image]

This is very strange.

$\hat{f}(\lambda_2)=2, \hat{f}(\lambda_3)=-0.7071$.

But since $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=4$, we have $2=-0.7071$.

---

More formal proof:

Assume $L$ has an eigenvalue with multiplicity greater than 1(as in the image above). Without loss of generality, let $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$. Then $\hat{f}(\lambda_2) = \hat{f}(\lambda_3)$.

By the definition, $\langle u_2 , f\rangle=\langle u_3 , f\rangle$.

Since $f$ is an **arbitrary** vector and $f$ has nothing to do with $L$ or $U$,  we have $u_2 = u_3$.

Then this contradicts that $L=U \Lambda U^{-1}$.

---

What is wrong here?

Please help

Comment: Which "some places" do this? Maybe there's context.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Actually there are so many "some places" but I think the first one is here: "The emerging field of signal processing on graphs: Extending high-dimensional data analysis to networks and other irregular domains"(https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6494675)

Comment: Oh, that doesn't look like there's context. That just looks like there's sloppiness (and maybe a desire to mirror the usual Fourier transform more closely than is possible).

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah it is definitely not well defined. I wonder how they plot those values when one eigenvalue has multiple f_hat values. Maybe they just added all of them. Very uncomfortable.